# How to know which text Jsoup remove?

Tags: java, jsoup

I have the following text:

```
text<html/>text
```

And use Jsoup library in order to clean up text from html content. Namely like code below:

```
Document clean = new Cleaner(none()).clean(myDirtyDoc);
```

I am going to log error for user like: `Malisious content was specified: "<html/>".`
But I don't know how properly identify line that Jsoup was clean.

I've tried to use StringUtils.difference(cleanedValue, value), but this method works in another way, namely documentation says:

```
Compares two Strings, and returns the portion where they differ.
(More precisely, return the remainder of the second String,
starting from where it's different from the first.)
```

As result it return string like this: `<html/>text`.

Will be good to know any diff tools that can be easily used in java for comparing strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[google-diff-match-patch](https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/)

The Diff Match and Patch libraries offer robust algorithms to perform the operations required for synchronizing plain text.

Diff:
Compare two blocks of plain text and efficiently return a list of differences.

Match:
Given a search string, find its best fuzzy match in a block of plain text. Weighted for both accuracy and location.

Patch:
Apply a list of patches onto plain text. Use best-effort to apply patch even when the underlying text doesn't match.

Currently available in Java, JavaScript, Dart, C++, C#, Objective C, Lua and Python. Regardless of language, each library features the same API and the same functionality. All versions also have comprehensive test harnesses.

There is a [Line or word diffs](https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/wiki/LineOrWordDiffs) wiki page which describes how to do line-by-line diffs.